# An alternative to NanoHTTPD that handles simultaneous connections?

Tags: java, apache, nanohttpd

I started using NanoHTTPD for a project. Indeed it is very good in its simplicity. Unfortunately it turned out that I need to handle simultaneous connections, for example I have a very long response and in the meanwhile the server shall not be blocked.

What do you recommend? I need it to be simple and feature rich as Nano.

Comment: Are you talking of https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd? Because as I see it now accepts simultaneous connections.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know. Back in 2012 it was not!

Answer (score 7):

NanoHttpd processes incoming requests with a simple 1-request/1-thread multi-threading model, and it's also multi-instance friendly so you can spin up multiple instance of the server to handle connections on different ports if you need to.

Comment: There's an issue with rapidly sent requests: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/issues/356